# Como realizar query que repita los 12 meses del año por cada tipo de grupo

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo una tabla **meses** con los respectivos 12 meses del año con su id, otra tabla **defectos** con los campos **maquina,fecha,manchas**
Mi idea es realizar una query que me muestre la suma de las manchas, por cada mes y maquina, mostrando los 12 meses del año. De la siguiente forma(el ejemplo lo realice en Excel).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy probando con la siguiente query

```
SELECT M.mes,D.maquina,IFNULL(manchas,0) as manchas
FROM
(
    SELECT * FROM meses
)M
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT maquina,MONTH(Fecha) as id,SUM(manchas) as manchas FROM defectos
    GROUP BY maquina,MONTH(fecha)
)D
ON M.id = D.id
```

Los datos me los muestra de la siguiente forma, es similar,pero no es el resultado que busco, estaría agradecido si alguien pudiera orientarme

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adjunto esquema de las tablas

Tablas Meses

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Maquinas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Defectos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tiene una table 'master data' de maquina?

Comment: Y por favor danos el schema de las tablas. Esto hace mas facil para resolverlo.

Comment: Si estimado, también poseo una tabla llamada maquinas, donde esta el nombre de cada una de ellas, adjuntare los esquemas en un respuesta.

Comment: ¿los ID de los meses van de 1 a 12?

Comment: Si van de 1 a 12 estimado.

Comment: Corregida la pregunta y eliminada respuesta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quisiera comenzar diciendo que en la forma normal, que es lo que se busca en los diagramas de Entidad/Relación en los que se basa el modelo relacional, es no guardar información redundante, tal como el nombre de la máquina.

Tu ya tienes una tabla de máquinas, pero en la tabla Defectos, en lugar de almacenar el `id` de la Máquina almacenas, de manera redundante, el nombre. Para colmo, lo almacenas en un campo que es de distinto tipo `varchar(30)` al de la tabla de máquinas `varchar(50)`.

El query que te dejo a continuación asume que has corregido primero ese problema. Si no quieres o no puedes corregirlo, entonces cambia la codición del `left join` o simplemente no incluyas a la tabla de Máquinas en la consulta, pues no tiene sentido si no están relacionadas.

Estoy

- Realizando un `cross join`, que es el producto cartesiano completo de la tabla de máquinas con la tabla de meses. Esto nos dará como resultado todos los meses en cada una de todas las máquinas.
- Asumiendo que la tabla Meses tiene como `id` el número que corresponde al mes, es decir, el `id` `1` es `'Enero'`, el `2` es `'Febrero'`, etc.
- Utilizando la función `coalesce()` para devolver 0 en el caso que no haya ningún registro en la tabla `Defectos` para un mes y máquina en particular.

```
select   Maquinas.Maquina
       , Meses.Mes
       , coalesce(sum(Defectos.Manchas), 0) Manchas
  from Maquinas
       cross join Meses
       left join Defectos on Defectos.idMaquina = Maquinas.ID and month(Defectos.Fecha) = meses.id
 group by Maquinas.Maquina
       , Meses.Mes
 order by Maquinas.Maquina
        , Meses.ID
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta , tomare en consideración las mejoras que me acabas de mencionar,la respuesta que me has dado es justamente lo que estaba buscando, salvo por una pequeña cosa, que necesito que me muestre las maquinas que están en la tabla defectos, ya que las que están en la tabla maquinas solo la uso como matriz cuando ingreso algún registro en la tabla defectos. Entonces no me muestra las maquinas que quiero.

Comment: Tomando en cuenta que este no es un servicio gratuito de escritura de consultas SQL, considero que, si partes de la consulta que he dejado en la respuesta, no te será difícil llegar al resultado que quieres. Como dije antes, lo primero que me viene a la mente es quitar la tabla de Maquinas de la consulta, ya que si no hay una verdadera relación, no tiene sentido incluirla. Al quitarla, automáticamente dejarán de aparecer las máquinas que no están en la tabla de defectos. Un saludo.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, eh quitada como usted menciona, la tabla maquinas de la consulta y eh logrado conseguir lo que buscaba. muchas gracias

Comment: Felicitaciones por el esfuerzo, de eso se trata, al final. Un saludo.